# React: Absolute Position In Child Components

Tags: reactjs, css-position, absolute

Introduction: I have a React component structure that looks like this.

**-- ParentComponent.tsx --**

```
<div>Some Content Here</div>
<ChildComponent/>
<div style={{ position: "relative", zIndex: "1" }}>
    Some Other Content -- should be covered when the absolutely positioned content
    inside of ChildComponent renders on the screen!
</div>
```

**-- ChildComponent.tsx --**

```
/* at the top of my render method */

const [booleanCondition, setBooleanCondition] = useState(false);
const toggleBooleanCondition = () => { setBooleanCondition(!booleanCondition); };

...
/* much later, in the return value of render method */

<div style={{ position: "relative", zIndex: "2" }}>
    Some Content Here, capable of calling toggleBooleanCondition()
    { booleanCondition ?
        <div style={{ position: "absolute", width: "400px", height: "400px" }}>
            Some Content Here. Should definitely cover the bottom <div> in parent!
        </div>
      : <></>
</div>
```

The toggle logic definitely works. The problem is, I would expect the `div` in `ChildComponent.tsx` to sit cleanly on top of the `div` in `ParentComponent.tsx`, which has a smaller z-index. However, this is not the case: the screenshot below shows that elements are being rendered in a random sort of order.

[image: Example of Problem]

I feel like the issue may be due to different components assigning different meanings to their own z-indexes. No matter how I played with position: relative, and z-index: , nothing seemed to change. Does anybody know of a reliable solution to this problem??

Answer (score 0):

My CSS background wasn't white. Lol.

```
 <div style={{ position: "absolute", width: "400px", height: "400px", backgroundColor: "white"}}>
```